# lost files on cut/paste to hard drive

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hard-drive-recovery

Last night, I mounted the main hard disk in Linux Mint 14. And cut/paste a lot of files (about 8GB) from home folder to the mounted disk.

When the operation finished, I suspend my computer, and a few hours later, I shut it down.

Today, when I tried to view my files (which I has copied them last night) I couldn't find them, neither in source folder (my home folder) and destination folder (a Windows drive on hard disk)

Where are them? Is it possible to recover them?

Comment: Was that mounted harddisk a USB drive? With NTFS? Did you stop using it? Did you stop to use the source harddisk?

Comment: It is my main hard disk. Not a USB drive.